# How Can I Iterate over each element in JSON array and join with rows in SQL SERVER

Tags: json, sql-server, pivot-table, dynamic-queries

I have this table named Employee I want to Pivot this into a new table:
[image: I have this table named Employee I want to Pivot this into a new table]

That is into the new table dynamically means the number of attributes of JSON data can be changed dynamically:

[image: That is into the new table dynamically means the number of attributes of JSON data can be changed dynamically]

How can I do in SQL Server 2017 dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OPENJSON` with a table definition for this.

You only need to use `REPLACE` to make it valid JSON

```sql
SELECT
  e.id,
  e.name,
  j.score,
  j.point
FROM Employee AS e
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(REPLACE(REPLACE(e.info, 'point', '"point"'), 'score', '"score"'))
  WITH (score int, point int) AS j;
```

Comment: `[{score: 20, point: 10}]` is not a valid JSON (for SQL Server)..

Comment: Good point, missed that, have fixed now

Comment: Thanks but I want a Dynamic query not a static one for SQL SERVER in which there is no fixed number of JSON attributes.

Comment: I strongly suggest you fix the data at source, this is simply not valid JSON